# Fill the form for the user php

Tags: php

When a user submits a form its validated using if statements, like this

```
if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 5)
{
    $data['errors'][] = 'Too short';
}
elseif ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password'])
{
    $data['errors'][] = 'doesnt match';
}
```

When validation is completed we check if there arent any errors

```
if (!$data['errors'])
```

And if it isnt we proceed and fill the data in to the database

However If there are errors, the USERS need to refill the whole form, I don't want that, I need to render back some data if it's legit

```
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $data['errors'][] = 'E-mail not valid';
}
```

Like here, if the password validation fails but the email validation is OK, I would want to give back the email already valued in the form. Would I need to put a else statement on every validation check like } else { $data['postback']['email']; } or could I do this on another easier way?

How can I do that?

Comment: The best course of action (in my opinion) is to submit the form via Ajax, and have the errors returned from the PHP file, to be rendered and displayed with JavaScript.

Comment: Store the values of each field to $_SESSION and then set those values to value part of `input`. So it'll look like `<input type='text' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>' />` or something like that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved with adding a else statement on the validation, if the validation was successfull I'd return the data to the rendering layout If something else on the validation failed.

```
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $data['errors'][] = 'E-mail not valid';
}
else
{
    $data['post']['email'] = $_POST['email'];
}
```

Then I'd simply pass back the $data array, containing the post.email variable and outputting it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use AJAX or Javascript/JQuery for fields you are checking, so the values of rest fields stay where they are.

Using this approach you can keep user input since you don't need to submit page to server. It also makes it better for server since it doesn't have to process extra requests.

For example: you have login and passwords fields. You need to validate if login already exists in database and also check if password fields match.
You can also have some text input called randomText that you don't need to validate.

So, for login field you use AJAX: when onBlur event occurs you send data to server, server checks if this login exists in database and sends answer back. Depending on your answer you use javascript/jQuery to show user an error. Be sure to disable page submitting if there are errors in page validation.
For passwords validation you just use Javascript and check if fields values match, if they don't - you write an error again.
And while you perform all these checks randomText field stays the same because you don't submit page to server.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put every value back in your rendered HTML input element. If you filter any values and you want that filtered value in your HTML you have to use the return value of the `filter_var` function.

```
<?php
$filtered = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $filtered ?>" />
```

for example. It will get a little easier if you use a templating system or framework which support some kind of form rendering like Zend Framework or Symfony.

Comment: I think you missunderstand, I simply want to return the data on validated data (that did pass the if statements) if something else goes wrong, like if you fail to match the passwords but type in the email I want to return the email to the form :) i could add a else statement and put a new $data variable, but I wonder if there are any smoother ways

Answer (score -1):

do something like this

```
<input value="<?= $_POST['email']; ?>" type="text" name="email" />
```

Comment: Please do not refill a password field for the user. You will send the password the user used in plain text over the internet.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" />
```